# What is the Kotlin equivalent of Swift's CharacterSet.decimalDigits and unicodeScalars

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, kotlin

I have the following code in Swift 5 that I'm having trouble converting to Kotlin:

```
let digits = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
for uni in character.unicodeScalars {
  if digits.contains(uni) {
    finalNumber = (Int(character)! * x) + finalNumber
  }
  else {
    return "999"
  }
}
```

The areas I am having trouble converting are with `CharacterSet.decimalDigits` and `character.unicodeScalars`. Anyone out there have any idea on how to translate these to Kotlin?

Comment: You're probably looking for `Character.UnicodeBlock`.

Comment: [`CharacterSet.decimalDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1408239-decimaldigits) represents decimals in both Indic scripts and Arabic. As far as I know, there is no equivalent [`Charset`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-charsets/index.html) in Kotlin. One more thing `Int(character)!` will fail with `character` equal to "١" and the like.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, the equivalent functionality to Swift's `CharacterSet.decimalDigits` and `unicodeScalars` can be achieved using the `Char` and `CharSequence` types along with some utility functions. Here's how you can achieve similar functionality:

1. Kotlin does not have a built-in `CharacterSet` type like Swift, but you can create a custom extension function on `Char` to check if it represents a decimal digit:

```kotlin
fun Char.isDecimalDigit(): Boolean {
    return this in '0'..'9'
}
```

You can use this extension function to check if a `Char` is a decimal digit.

2. To iterate over the Unicode scalar values of a `CharSequence` in Kotlin, you can use the `codePoints()` extension function and convert each code point back to a `Char`:

```kotlin
fun CharSequence.unicodeScalars(): Sequence<Char> {
    return this.codePoints().asSequence().map { it.toChar() }
}
```

This extension function allows you to obtain a sequence of `Char` representing the Unicode scalar values of a `CharSequence`, which could be a `String` or any other sequence of characters.

Here's an example of how you can use these functions:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val str = "abc123"
    
    for (char in str) {
        if (char.isDecimalDigit()) {
            println("$char is a decimal digit.")
        }
    }
    
    val unicodeScalars = str.unicodeScalars()
    for (scalar in unicodeScalars) {
        println(scalar)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 is a decimal digit.
2 is a decimal digit.
3 is a decimal digit.
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

In the above example, the `isDecimalDigit()` function is used to check if each character in the `str` string is a decimal digit. The `unicodeScalars()` function is used to iterate over the Unicode scalar values of the `str` string and print them.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you want to do here, what is `x` and what type does `character` have. It would be nice to have this info in the question. But if you want to check if the char of the string is a unicode digit you can do smth like that (since every `Char` in Kotlin is a unicode char already):

```
for (uni in string) {
  if (uni in kotlin.text.CharCategory.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER) {
    finalNumber = uni.toInt() * x + finalNumber
  } else {
    return "999"
  }
}
```